# How to reuse a new view in MVVM with Caliburn.Micro and Ninject

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, ninject, caliburn.micro

I am testing the possibility to modify dynamically the structure of Grid control (number of Rows/Columns for example).

I am using last version Caliburn.Micro and Ninject and use a [GridHelpers](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/) (i have modified) to have the possibility to bind number of Rows and Columns.

The full code of my application is available on [Github](https://github.com/Frenchy62620/Librairies)

I have created an usercontrol MyGridView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GridHelpersSample.MyGridView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:gh="clr-namespace:GridHelpers;assembly=GridHelpers"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridHelpersSample"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonViewModels}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding GridRow}" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding GridColumn}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action OnButtonClick($dataContext)]"
                                Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                </DataTemplate >
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid ShowGridLines="true" 
                        gh:GridHelpers.RowCount = "{Binding RowCount, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              gh:GridHelpers.ColumnCount = "{Binding ColumnCount, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              gh:GridHelpers.StarRows = "{Binding StarRows, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              gh:GridHelpers.StarColumns = "{Binding StarColumns, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              gh:GridHelpers.PixelRows = "{Binding PixelRows, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              gh:GridHelpers.PixelColumns = "{Binding PixelColumns, Mode=TwoWay}" >

                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <!-- Now define a container that will host the ItemsControl -->
            <!--<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate >
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >-->
        </ItemsControl >
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

the view model associated:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace GridHelpersSample
{
    public class MyGridViewModel : Screen
    {
        public BindableCollection<ButtonViewModel> ButtonViewModels { get; set; }

        public MyGridViewModel(Main2ViewModel main2ViewModel)
        {
            RowCount = main2ViewModel.RowCount;
            ColumnCount = main2ViewModel.ColumnCount;
            StarRows = main2ViewModel.StarRows;
            StarColumns = main2ViewModel.StarColumns;
            PixelRows = main2ViewModel.PixelRows;
            PixelColumns = main2ViewModel.PixelColumns;
            ButtonViewModels = main2ViewModel.ButtonViewModels;
        }

        #region datas for defining grid
        private string rowCount;
        public string RowCount
        {
            get { return rowCount; }
            set
            {
                rowCount = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RowCount);
            }
        }
        private string columnCount;
        public string ColumnCount
        {
            get { return columnCount; }
            set
            {
                columnCount = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ColumnCount);
            }
        }
        private string starRows;
        public string StarRows
        {
            get { return starRows; }
            set
            {
                starRows = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => StarRows);
            }
        }
        private string starColumns;
        public string StarColumns
        {
            get { return starColumns; }
            set
            {
                starColumns = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => StarColumns);
            }
        }

        private string pixelRows;
        public string PixelRows
        {
            get { return pixelRows; }
            set
            {
                pixelRows = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PixelRows);
            }
        }
        private string pixelColumns;

        public string PixelColumns
        {
            get { return pixelColumns; }
            set
            {
                pixelColumns = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PixelColumns);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public void OnButtonClick(ButtonViewModel context)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

---

the Main2View has a content control and all the settings to define the structure of the grid defined in the usercontrol.

```
<Window x:Class="GridHelpersSample.Main2View"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:gh="clr-namespace:GridHelpers;assembly=GridHelpers"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"       
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridHelpersSample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Main2View" Height="600" Width="1000">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <!--<Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="[Event LostFocus] = [Action TextBox_LostFocus($source, $this)]" />-->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Name" Value="RowCount">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Name" Value="ColumnCount">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid"
        gh:GridHelpers.RowCount="2"
        gh:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="1"
        gh:GridHelpers.StarRows="1"
        gh:GridHelpers.StarColumns="*">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" >
            <Separator />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Label Content="RowCount:" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="RowCount" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
                <Label Content="StarRows:" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="StarRows" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
                <Label Content="PixelRows:" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="PixelRows" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
                <Button x:Name="Valider" Content="Valider la saisie" Width="100" 
                        Margin="30,20,0,-20" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Label Content="ColumnCount:" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="ColumnCount" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
                <Label Content="StarColumns:" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="StarColumns" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
                <Label Content="PixelColumns:" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="PixelColumns" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
                <Button Width="100" Visibility="Hidden" Height="0" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Separator />
        </StackPanel>
        <ContentControl x:Name="myGridViewModel" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

the code of Main2ViewModel:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Syntax;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GridHelpersSample
{
    public class Main2ViewModel : Screen
    {
        private readonly IResolutionRoot _resolutionRoot;
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;
        public BindableCollection<ButtonViewModel> ButtonViewModels { get; set; }
        public MyGridViewModel myGridViewModel { get; set; }
        public Main2ViewModel(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot, IKernel kernel) 
        {
            _resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
            _kernel = kernel;
            RowCount = "3";
            ColumnCount = "3";
            StarRows = "*";
            StarColumns = "*";
            PixelRows = "";
            PixelColumns = "";

            AddNewContent();
        }

        #region datas for defining grid
        private string rowCount;
        public string RowCount
        {
            get { return rowCount; }
            set
            {
                rowCount = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RowCount);
            }
        }
        private string columnCount;
        public string ColumnCount
        {
            get { return columnCount; }
            set
            {
                columnCount = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ColumnCount);
            }
        }
        private string starRows;
        public string StarRows
        {
            get { return starRows; }
            set
            {
                starRows = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => StarRows);
            }
        }
        private string starColumns;
        public string StarColumns
        {
            get { return starColumns; }
            set
            {
                starColumns = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => StarColumns);
            }
        }

        private string pixelRows;
        public string PixelRows
        {
            get { return pixelRows; }
            set
            {
                pixelRows = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PixelRows);
            }
        }
        private string pixelColumns;

        public string PixelColumns
        {
            get { return pixelColumns; }
            set
            {
                pixelColumns = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PixelColumns);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public void Valider()
        {            
            AddNewContent();
        }
        public List<ButtonViewModel> CreateButton()
        {
            var myView = _resolutionRoot.Get<Main2View>();
            var t = myView.MainGrid;
            var list = new List<ButtonViewModel>();
            for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(RowCount); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < int.Parse(ColumnCount); j++)
                {
                    var button = new ButtonViewModel
                    {
                        Content = $"R{i} C{j}",
                        GridRow = i,
                        GridColumn = j
                    };

                    list.Add(button);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }

        private void AddNewContent()
        {
            ButtonViewModels = new BindableCollection<ButtonViewModel>(CreateButton());
            myGridViewModel = new MyGridViewModel(this);
        }
    }
}
```

---

All is fine during the intialization of view/viewmodel, but the problem begins when i change the value of RowCount or RowColumn and i click on button.

i am waiting the initializatoon of new view , but its not the case, the view MyGridView is not reloaded..

this is the boostrapper:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using Ninject;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace GridHelpersSample
{
    public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        private IKernel kernel;
        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<IWindowManager>().To<WindowManager>().InSingletonScope();
            kernel.Bind<IEventAggregator>().To<EventAggregator>().InSingletonScope();
            kernel.Bind<MyGridViewModel>().ToSelf().InTransientScope();
            //kernel.Bind<MyGridViewModel>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
            var bindings0 = kernel.GetBindings(typeof(MyGridViewModel));
            //var bindings1 = kernel.GetBindings(typeof(MainViewModel));
        }
        protected override async void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayRootViewForAsync<Main2ViewModel>();
        }
        protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
        {
            return kernel.Get(service);
        }
        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
        {
            return kernel.GetAll(service);
        }
        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            kernel.Inject(instance);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I dont arrive to relaunch a new view even i use InTransientScope()
which indicates to use a new instance of view.. but maybe i am missing something..

In anyways it seems the applicationto have a problem, because when i close the main view, the debugger doesnt finish and i have to stop the application with the red button in VS2022

i have tested with the use of Unbind but no luck

```
    private void AddNewContent()
    {
        ButtonViewModels = new BindableCollection<ButtonViewModel>(CreateButton());
        if (myGridViewModel == null)
        {
            myGridViewModel = new MyGridViewModel(this);
            return;
        }
        //_kernel.Unbind<MyGridViewModel>();
        _kernel.Unbind<MyGridView>();
        //_kernel.Bind<MyGridViewModel>().To<MyGridViewModel>();
        _kernel.Bind<MyGridView>().To<MyGridView>();
        myGridViewModel = new MyGridViewModel(this);
    }
```

Comment: Did you know that the that the Listiew supports a table like GridView? Then there is also the DataGrid. Using a basic ItemsControl is rarely the right choice as it doesn't support scrolling and more important doesn't support performance features like UI virtualization (which is supported by all advanced ItemsControl types like ListView or DataGrid).

Comment: Using a DataGrid would drastically simplify your code I guess. You can then chose the DataTable as data structure for the view. This eliminates the loose column and row data collections and weird table (Grid) configuration.

Comment: For example you could change the columns of a DataTable and reassign it to the DataGrid to have the changes reflect. Currently it looks like the you have not implemented any mechanism to invalidate the layout of the items panel when the properties of the GridHelpers (attachged?) properties have changed. Usiing a DataTable and DataGrid eliminates all this layout related code and offers more control over data and data view (the DataGrid is a quite advanced control).

Comment: @BionicCode, i agree with what you say. Its just a test to understant how to reload a new instance of view using caliburn and container...  its easy to see the result with Grid because after the initialization, you cant change the number of rows/columns.. i just want to know if a solution exists for this type of problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have found the solution:

In `Main2ViewModel`, just refactor my variable myGridViewModel with `NotifyOfPropertyChange()`:

```
    private MyGridViewModel _myGridViewModel;
    public MyGridViewModel myGridViewModel
    {
        get { return _myGridViewModel; }
        set
        {
            _myGridViewModel = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => myGridViewModel);
        }
    }
```

so i can write the method AddNewContent like this:

```
    private void AddNewContent()
    {
        ButtonViewModels = new BindableCollection<ButtonViewModel>(CreateButton());
        myGridViewModel = new MyGridViewModel(this);
    }
```

---

so in `bootstrapper.cs` file, no need to Bind MyGridViewModel :

```
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IWindowManager>().To<WindowManager>().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<IEventAggregator>().To<EventAggregator>().InSingletonScope();
    }
```

And no more problem when i quit application